# How to move pygame rects in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I am trying to create a series of "boids" at random locations, which fly at random speeds, but I am having some trouble moving the rects which are in a list, although I can draw them. I am using a provided vector module, the entire code and the module can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/PotatoPope/85965d57d2c65b03ab167e1b08f51403). The [png](https://imageshack.com/i/poz0FEqup) I am using for the sprites.

Update: I got a rect moving, by using the instance position vector instead of the class vector. But now only one boid is drawn. I suspect that more boids are drawn at the same exact position.

```
class Boid():
    def __init__(self, screen):

        self.bird = pygame.image.load("birdie.png")
        self._pos = Vector2D(random.randint(0, screen.get_width()),
                             random.randint(0, screen.get_height()))
        self._vel = Vector2D((random.randint(1, 10) / 5.0),
                             (random.randint(1, 10) / 5.0))
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 5)
        self.bird_rect = self.bird.get_rect(center=(self._pos.x, self._pos.y))
        self._boids = []

    def add_boid(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self._boids.append(Boid(screen))

    def move_boids(self):
        s = Screen()
        #self.bird_rect.move_ip(self._vel.x, self._vel.y)
        self._pos += (self._vel * self.speed)

        #bounds check
        if self._pos.x + self.bird_rect.width >= s.width:
            self._pos.x  = s.width - self.bird_rect.width
            self._vel.x *= -1
        elif self._pos.x <= 0:
            self._pos.x  = 0
            self._vel.x *= -1

        if self._pos.y - self.bird_rect.height <= 0:
            self._pos.y = self.bird_rect.height
            self._vel.y *= -1
        elif self._pos.y >= s.height:
            self._pos.y = s.height - self.bird_rect.height
            self._vel.y *= -1

    def draw_boids(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            print(len(self._boids))

        for boid in self._boids:
                self.boidRect = pygame.Rect(self.bird_rect)
                #edit: changed boid._pos.x and y to self._pos.x and y
                self.boidRect.x = self._pos.x
                self.boidRect.y = self._pos.y
                screen.blit(self.bird, self.boidRect)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over all boids in the `self._boids` list and update their `_pos` and `bird_rect` attributes to move them.

```
def move_boids(self):
    s = Screen()
    for boid in self._boids:
        boid._pos += boid._vel * boid.speed
        boid.bird_rect.center = boid._pos

        # Bounds check.
        if boid._pos.x + boid.bird_rect.width >= s.width:
            boid._pos.x  = s.width - boid.bird_rect.width
            boid._vel.x *= -1
        elif boid._pos.x <= 0:
            boid._pos.x  = 0
            boid._vel.x *= -1

        if boid._pos.y - boid.bird_rect.height <= 0:
            boid._pos.y = boid.bird_rect.height
            boid._vel.y *= -1
        elif boid._pos.y >= s.height:
            boid._pos.y = s.height - boid.bird_rect.height
            boid._vel.y *= -1
```

You can also simplify the `draw` method a bit.

```
def draw_boids(self):
    # Blit all boids at their rects.
    for boid in self._boids:
        screen.blit(boid.bird, boid.bird_rect)
```

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to refactor the `Boid` class, because it's kind of odd that it is also the container of the boid objects. And better load the image once when the program starts, not every time you create an instance.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. First of all, I'm getting an "Typerror: invalid rect assignement" on "boid.bird_rect.center = boid._pos". Secondly, how would you suggest that I "refactor" the Class? Should I put the container (I assume you mean the list) in another class/method?

Comment: *"Typerror: invalid rect assignement" on "boid.bird_rect.center = boid._pos"* - Try to use pygame's [vector class](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) or convert your `_pos` vector into a tuple. --- *"Secondly, how would you suggest that I "refactor" the Class?"* This is the wrong website for such questions. Make sure that your code works correctly and then post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok I changed "boid.bird_rect.center = boid._pos" to "   boid.bird_rect.x = boid._pos.x and 
   boid.bird_rect.y = boid._pos.y" and now it works, although the boundary check isn't working, but I can fix that on my own. Thanks again!